# simplexml_load_file : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I want to parse an XML document in PHP with SimpleXML.
I used `simplexml_load_file` and I got this error:

`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): [myfile] parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document in /www/[...]/myphpfile.php on line 7`

I have searched on Google and the problem seems to be that there is some whitespace before the tags in the XML document. I checked, there is no whitespace before.

Here is my code:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$sxml=simplexml_load_file($xml);
if ($sxml) {
 echo '<h2>'.$xml.'</h2>';
 echo '<p>author: <textarea>';
 foreach($sxml->author as $author) {
  if($author!=$strXML)
   echo $author.'\n';
  }
  echo '</textarea></p>';
}else {
  echo "Failed loading XML\n";
  foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error)
    echo "\t", $error->message;
}
```

**Edit:** error is `Failed loading XML XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document Extra content at the end of the document`

The first tag of the XML document is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: Where is your XML file source?

Comment: Two children directory after.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error following an example from Symfony2 :

```
<!-- validators.en.xliff -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>author.name.not_blank</source>
                <target>Saisissez un nom</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

The problem was the comment on the first line !

Answer (score 2):

Suppose, I found (actually I meet this error first time).

1. I tried an XML file that start very first line with `<?xml ...` (no error)
2. I tried an XML file that start very first line with `[space or/and new line]<?xml ...` (has error)

// both error (xml.xml contents)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
// and
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>


$xml = simplexml_load_file("xml.xml");
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents("xml.xml"));
```

So, be sure XML file starts with `<?xml ...` or a valid XML tags (I mean 1. line), remove all spaces from first line.

Answer (score 1):

Just strip whitespaces from beginning:

```
new \SimpleXMLElement(
  trim($xmlString)
);
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the $xsml first then use it in the if.